# IS NULL function not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I've tested `IS NULL` function provided by Google BigQuery, but it doesn't seems to give correct results.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
id   age   gender   password
1,   11,    NULL,     NULL
1,   11,   "NULL",   "NULL"
1,   11,   "null",   "null"
1,     ,    NULL,     NULL
```

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT id, age, gender, password, id IS NULL, age IS NULL, gender IS NULL, password IS NULL 
FROM privatedata.testnull
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Row id  age gender  password f0_    f1_      f2_     f3_     
1   1   11   NULL    NULL   false   false   false   false    
2   1   11   NULL    NULL   false   false   false   false    
3   1   11   null    null   false   false   false   false    
4   1   0    NULL    NULL   false   false   false   false
```

But this SQL works:

```
SELECT NULL IS NULL, COUNT(*) FROM privatedata:testnull
```

So I'm not sure if `IS NULL` is working or not. Also I'm confused with how I would insert null data in string format and numeric format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:

For very old tables there was an issue where we did not preserve the between an empty field and a NULL one. This issue should by fixed for any table that was created after March, 2013.

OLD ANSWER:

I believe the issue is that for string fields, we're interpreting the NULL as the string "NULL". What if you just use `, ,` for the string values?

The one that is surprising is that age in row 4 should be showing up as null. It looks like something is wrong with the IS_NULL function. I've filed a bug internally. The IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED() function, however, should return what you expect (e.g. IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED for age in row 4 would return fasle).

Comment: If i put empty values(", , , ") for string values and run the same query, I still get "false" for IS NULL output

Comment: The null issue turns out to be a known internal bug. You should use IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED for now.